# HTML&CSS3*JavaScript advanced scrolling

Tags: css, html, scroll

I need to create a tool with HTML, CSS3 and JavaScript. It will contain some horizontal and vertical scrollbars to use in order to see all the content properly, keeping fixed sizes of some elements. This is the layout that tries to explain what I want
[image]

So, I have a **#main** DIV containing a **#left** and **#right** DIV. Left DIV contains two DIVs and right DIV contains another 2 DIVs.
Now, I want to create a vertical scroll-bar (vscroll1) to scroll up and down through both **#content** and **#menu** DIVs (at the same time, like they where the same DIV).
On the other hand I want a horizontal scroll-bar (hscroll2) to scroll to the left and right through **#content** and **#left_top_div**, at the same time, like it would be the same content.

I think I may have 2 ways: some CSS+HTML trick or by using JavaScript.
Right now, If attach scrollbars to **#leftdiv** (`overflow:auto`), it will scroll the **#left_top_div** and **#content** (DIVs contained by it) as I want it, but vertically it will scroll only **#content**, not the **#menu** DIV. So, that's a problem.
I could use JavaScript with the `.onscroll()` event to change #menu topMargin, but there's a small delay which doesn't look good. What do you advise me to do? I just need some tips or techniques (well, some example code is also appreciated).
Thanks to everybody for, at least, reading all my question.

Comment: Looks like a job for framesets — ! \*is murdered\*

Answer (score 1):

Set all the div's CSS overflows to 'hidden' by default. Then...

Wrap #menu and #content in a fixed-height div with an `overflow-y: scroll;`

Then make #menu and #content fixed-width divs with an `overflow-x: scroll`

Comment: Your answer enlightened me a little bit more. Yet, if I do what you say then #left_top_div won't scroll along with #content, horizontally.

Comment: @ali that is true. I missed that requirement. That gets a bit trickier. You may have to resort to javascript at that point and watch for scrolling of one div and then sync the others.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but a small delay in the position change make it look like a drawing problem. I need some JavaScript trick to make it faster. I use marginLeft to move the #left_top_div at the same position as #content but the scrolling of #content is faster.